# error: cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, dagger2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пишу проект с использование dagger2. Всё отлично работало, но, дописав новую фичу, запускаю компилятор, а мне в ответ, что не может найти класс DaggerAppComponent, хотя раньше всё работало.

Application:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    component = buildComponent();
}

private AppComponent buildComponent(){

    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(this))
            .build();
}
```

Gradle(Module:app)

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.9"
```

Comment: Если до этого работало, а потом перестало, то у вас где-то в новой фиче ошибка компиляции. Смотрите логи - там будет указано где.

Comment: Отключил фичу и всё равно не работает. Ошибка возникает на стадии создания Application, так что вряд ли в этом проблема.

Comment: Т.е. оно при запуске падает? И в логах пусто?..

Comment: Да, аппка даже не инсталится на телефон. Добавил скрин в топик.

Comment: Не надо скринов, надо текст. Возможно у вас в реалме в одном из классов конструктора дефолтного нет

Comment: Да, точно! Теперь работает. Спасибо:)

Answer (score 5):

Т.к. класс `DaggerAppComponent` создаётся даггером на этапе компиляции, то любая ошибка компиляции не даст ему создасться. В этом случае надо смотреть в логи и смотреть какая у вас ошибка компиляции. В данном случае у вас не было дефолтного конструктора в одном из классов-моделей реалма.