# Moxy. Не могу запустить "sample-github" c официального репозитория GitHub

Tags: android, dagger2, android-gradle, moxy

Хочу изучить Moxy и Dagger2.

По Moxy есть пример (sample-github) в официальном [репозитории GitHub](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy).

Я хочу "поковырять" их пример, но проблема в том, что при попытке запустить проект получаю сообщение:

> C:...\sample-github\src\main\java\com\arellomobile\mvp\sample\github\app\GithubApp.java
>   Error:(8, 45) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerAppComponent

```
package com.arellomobile.mvp.sample.github.app;

...

import com.arellomobile.mvp.sample.github.di.AppComponent;
import com.arellomobile.mvp.sample.github.di.DaggerAppComponent;
import com.arellomobile.mvp.sample.github.di.modules.ContextModule;

...
```

Пробовал создавать новый проект и переносить только sample-gitgub, т.к. sample-kotlin запускается. При попытке очистить и пересоздать проект вылетают ошибки gradle относящиеся к sample-kotlin. Т.к. только начинаю изучать Moxy и Dagger2, не могу самостоятельно разобраться и исправить ошибку, что бы запустить проект.

Comment: Действительно такого файла нет, пишите issue.

Comment: @SergeMarkov а с чего он должен быть, если он геный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно повысить версию в build.gradle для dagger до 2.16

Т.е. в build.gradle(Module: sample-github)

```
def support = '27.1.1'
def retrofit = '2.1.0'
def dagger = '2.7' // заменить на 2.16
def butterKnife = "8.4.0"

dependencies {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Т.к. класс DaggerAppComponent создаётся даггером на этапе компиляции,
>   то любая ошибка компиляции не даст ему создасться. В этом случае надо
>   смотреть в логи и смотреть какая у вас ошибка компиляции. В данном
>   случае у вас не было дефолтного конструктора в одном из
>   классов-моделей реалма.

Ответ взят отсюда - [ссылка на ответ от ЮрийСПб♦ ru.so.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660900/error-cannot-find-symbol-class-daggerappcomponent)

Посмотрите что пишет в логах.

Comment: Мне пока сложно разобраться в потоке ошибок. Но кажется понял в чем проблема. Спасибо, попробую исправить. Эту ошибку получается допустили/недоглядели разработчики?